# Java - Run Powershell and parse commands to it

Tags: java, powershell, command

iam working on a project for a Service Desk. This Service Desk have round about 10 various tools to get the result for the customers. I already have put this tools to one Java-Tool together. 
One thing do not want work. 
The customers work on several XenApp/XenDesktop Servers. From the Server the customers ar loged in, i wanna get the RAM Avarage Util to show them in the GUI of my tool.

I wanne run a powershell ones and paste multiple times commands to the powershell. But it want work. In my example the program hangs in the while loop

`while(!file.exists() & !file.canWrite()){}`

after it runs one time.

My question is, can i run a powershell once and paste commands to it multiple times? In C# ive tryed it and it works. But i want rewrite 7000 lines of code in C#.

Sorry for my bad english. I hope you understand my problem and can help me.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class SystemAvarageUtil {

    public static void getSystemAvarageUtil(String desktopServer, String appServer, String personalNummer) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("PowerShell -NoExit -Command -");
        while(personalNummer.equals("XXXXXX")){

            File file = new File("H:\\sdassistence\\tmp\\Util.tmp");
            if(file.exists()){
                file.delete();
            }

            PrintWriter commands = new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream(),true);
            //desktopServer RAM
            commands.println("$ComputerNameDesktop=\""+ desktopServer +"\"");
            commands.println("$ComputerSystemDesktop = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerNameDesktop -Class Win32_operatingsystem -Property CSName, TotalVisibleMemorySize, FreePhysicalMemory");
            commands.println("$MachineNameDesktop = $ComputerSystemDesktop.CSName");
            commands.println("$FreePhysicalMemoryDesktop = ($ComputerSystemDesktop.FreePhysicalMemory) / (1mb)");
            commands.println("$TotalVisibleMemorySizeDesktop = ($ComputerSystemDesktop.TotalVisibleMemorySize) / (1mb)");
            commands.println("$TotalVisibleMemorySizeRDesktop = \"{0:N2}\" -f $TotalVisibleMemorySizeDesktop");
            commands.println("$TotalFreeMemPercDesktop = ($FreePhysicalMemoryDesktop/$TotalVisibleMemorySizeDesktop)*100");
            commands.println("$TotalFreeMemPercRDesktop = \"{0:N2}\" -f $TotalFreeMemPercDesktop");
            //commands.println("$TotalVisibleMemorySizeRDesktop GB");
            //commands.println("$TotalFreeMemPercRDesktop %");

            //appServer RAM
            commands.println("$ComputerNameApp=\""+ appServer +"\"");
            commands.println("$ComputerSystemApp = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerNameApp -Class Win32_operatingsystem -Property CSName, TotalVisibleMemorySize, FreePhysicalMemory");
            commands.println("$MachineNameApp = $ComputerSystemApp.CSName");
            commands.println("$FreePhysicalMemoryApp = ($ComputerSystemApp.FreePhysicalMemory) / (1mb)");
            commands.println("$TotalVisibleMemorySizeApp = ($ComputerSystemApp.TotalVisibleMemorySize) / (1mb)");
            commands.println("$TotalVisibleMemorySizeRApp = \"{0:N2}\" -f $TotalVisibleMemorySizeApp");
            commands.println("$TotalFreeMemPercApp = ($FreePhysicalMemoryApp/$TotalVisibleMemorySizeApp)*100");
            commands.println("$TotalFreeMemPercRApp = \"{0:N2}\" -f $TotalFreeMemPercApp");
            //commands.println("$TotalVisibleMemorySizeRApp GB");
            //commands.println("$TotalFreeMemPercRApp %");


            commands.println("$TotalVisibleMemorySizeRDesktop+\";\"+$TotalFreeMemPercRDesktop+\";\"+$TotalVisibleMemorySizeRApp+\";\"+$TotalFreeMemPercRApp | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 -FilePath \"H:\\sdassistence\\tmp\\Util.tmp\"");
            commands.println("exit");
            commands.close();


            while(!file.exists() & !file.canWrite()){}
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String test[] = in.readLine().split(";");
            System.out.println(test[0] + " " + test[1] + " " + test[2]);
            fr.close();in.close();process.destroy();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        getSystemAvarageUtil("DesktopServer","AppServer","XXXXXX");

    }


}
```

Comment: There are a few possibilities why this fails. You should first consume the error and output streams of the process to check if there is an error or if it hangs because it needs its output consumed. Might have been in a similar problem once, this site helped me a lot: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Comment: Nice! Big Thanks. I will try this tomorow and give you a feedback!